# Outer glow effect to border

Tags: wpf, border, glow, bitmapeffect

How to provide the outer glow effect to border?

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <Grid.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.5" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.8" RadiusY="0.8">
            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF123B5F" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF001F31" />
            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Border Width="180" Height="180" Margin="10" Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
        <Border.BitmapEffect>
            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" GlowSize="3" Opacity="1" />
        </Border.BitmapEffect>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I have tried this but it not working

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`BitmapEffects` are no longer supported in .NET 4.0.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx)

> Important In the .NET Framework 4 or later, the BitmapEffect class is
>   obsolete. If you try to use the BitmapEffect class, you will get an
>   obsolete exception. The non-obsolete alternative to the BitmapEffect
>   class is the Effect class. In most situations, the Effect class is
>   significantly faster.

It isn't the same thing but you can try with a `DropShadowEffect` with `ShadowDepth` close to 0 instead.

*Example*

```
<Border Width="180" Height="180" Margin="10" Background="Transparent"
        BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" Opacity="1.0">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"
                          Color="White"
                          Opacity="1"
                          BlurRadius="5"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

Comparison between the `BitmapEffects` you had and `DropShadowEffect` above. `DropShadowEffect` to the right.

[image]